# ¿Es correcta la asignación de "null" en el siguiente método?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

ante todo gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer.
Resulta que estoy trabajando con el IDE Intellij Idea, el cual me da el siguiente error en mi código:

> Variable 'result' initializer 'null' is redundant less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Inspection info: This inspection points out the cases where a variable value is never used after its assignment, i.e.:  
> - the variable never gets read after assignment OR  
> - the value is always overwritten with another assignment before the next variable read OR  
> - the variable initializer is redundant (for one of the above two reasons)

El mismo dice que la asignación de `null` a la variable **result** es reduntante.

Mi código:

```
public class AlgoBOImpl implements AlgoBO {

@Inject
@DAO
private AlgoDAOImpl algoDAO;
private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlgoBOImpl.class);
private final static String BO_ERROR_GET_ALGO_BY_ID   = "Error de negocio al recuperar algo por ID.";

public AlgoDTO getAlgoById(long id) throws BusinessException {
    AlgoDTO result = null;
    try {
        result = this.getAlgoDAO().getAlgoById(id);
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        LOGGER.error(BO_ERROR_GET_ALGO_BY_ID, e);
        throw new BusinessException(e);
    }

return result;

}

public AlgoDAOImpl getAlgoDAO() {
    return algoDAO;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Es redundante porque esa variable solo se pisa con lo que retorne `this.getAlgoDAO().getAlgoById(id);` Ahora, si tu método en caso de error solo escribiera en el log y no lanzara una BusinessException, entonces si no sería redundante.

Answer (score 0):

mira lo que sucede es que ese error te lo da el compilador debido a que las clases son tipos que cuando creas una instancia de ellas automáticamente se inicializan en null, es por eso que te lo marca como error.

Comment: Las variables locales no se *inicializan* a ningún valor